# Map is returing Empty{} value for non existing key after Struts migrating from 2.3 to 2.5

Tags: struts2

We have currently did Struts migration from 2.3 to 2.5.After that facing weird issue with Util Map.
This is existing code which is working fine with Struts 2.3.Please find code snippet eg

```
final Map requestMap = ( Map ) formBean ;

requestMap.get("empname"); ---here empname is non existing key in map
```

Exceptected result:null

But getting following output

```
Empty{name='empname'}
```

Please let me know if anyone aware of this? Really stuck with this issue.

Comment: Nobody knows it since you didn't post debugging details.

Comment: What's `formBean`? How are you showing the "output"?